# C# Entity Framework One variable mapped to two DB columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Like the question title says, I have two DB columns mapped to one variable (or so it seems), and I'm looking to correct that.

The following is my entity's property:

```
 [Required, AuditField("Project", typeof(Project))]
 public Guid Project_Id { get; set; }
 public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
```

And in my DB, I used to have:

```
 CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tasks_dbo.Projects_ProjectId] FOREIGN KEY ([Project_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([Id])
```

as well as

```
 CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tasks_dbo.Projects_ProjectId] FOREIGN KEY ([Project_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([Id])
```

due to a problematic rename. I want to cut this down to just one Project_Id, but I'm not sure how. If I remove one of these statements (And the related FK's), specifically the Project_Id I receive the following error:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Project_Id'.
```

Invalid column name 'Project_Id'.

But if I rename it to Project_Id1 and rerun, I get the following error:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Project_Id1'
```

It was working when I had both in at the same time, which is what led me to the conclusion I had reached earlier. I've been unable to find related posts on StackOverflow or anywhere else, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Added both back in, it's working again. I'm just going to keep this as-is for now.